# Query for selecting records from a table but the using a list thats on another table

Tags: database, ms-access, select

I Need run a query that selects all the Data for selected vendors (Key words) but selection list (Key words) is on another Table.

Currently I am using: - I use only the key words in place of "Vendor"
Like "*Vendor A*" Or Like "*Vendor B*" Or Like "*Vendor C*" Or Like "*Vendor D*" Or Like "*Vendor E*"

Currently I have to add new vendors to this Query to get the report but this query is growing big and I need give this to a staff who does not know anything about Access and I was wondering if I could create a table for these key words where just updating the table list (key words) will allow access to look for these key words in another table and pull the records.
Hope this explains what I need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your query and tables look like?What should the desired results look like? You should post specific questions. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  Put put each criteria on a separate row of a new table.  Put both tables in the same query, with no joins.  Pull all of the fields from the source table, with a constraint that looks something like "instr(keyfield,criteria)>0", or "keyfield=criteria" if you expect an exact match.  You may get duplicates if the key matches more than one criteria - if so, you can use group by to get rid of them.

And you should still look at the reference that Rene suggested above.